Linux Perf Stat -> results and intel meteor lake (p-cores only test)
Device -> Asus Zenbook 14 (Intel Meteor Lake 155H)
ubuntu 24.04 lts
uname -r == 6.8.0-45-generic
From running perf stat, i can see entries for
cpu_atom/instructions/
cpu_atom/cycles/
cpu_atom/branches/
Are those the results from Efficiency-cores (cpu_atom)?
Can i run perf stat strictly on the Performance-Cores? (which are cpu_core 0 to 5)
lscpu --all --extended
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE    MAXMHZ   MINMHZ       MHZ
  0    0      0    0 16:16:4:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000 1731.5070
  1    0      0    1 8:8:2:0          yes 4800.0000 400.0000 1991.5780
  2    0      0    1 8:8:2:0          yes 4800.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  3    0      0    2 12:12:3:0        yes 4800.0000 400.0000 1684.4030
  4    0      0    2 12:12:3:0        yes 4800.0000 400.0000 1889.0811
  5    0      0    0 16:16:4:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000 1271.9000
  6    0      0    3 20:20:5:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000 1669.7340
  7    0      0    3 20:20:5:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  8    0      0    4 24:24:6:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000  400.0000
  9    0      0    4 24:24:6:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000 1838.1899
 10    0      0    5 28:28:7:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000 1856.5320
 11    0      0    5 28:28:7:0        yes 4500.0000 400.0000  400.0000
 12    0      0    6 0:0:0:0          yes 3800.0000 400.0000 1537.6290
 13    0      0    7 2:2:0:0          yes 3800.0000 400.0000 1502.0179
 14    0      0    8 4:4:0:0          yes 3800.0000 400.0000 1341.5179
 15    0      0    9 6:6:0:0          yes 3800.0000 400.0000 1461.8240
 16    0      0   10 1:0              yes 3800.0000 400.0000  400.0000
 17    0      0   11 10:10:1:0        yes 3800.0000 400.0000  400.0000
 18    0      0   12 1:0              yes 3800.0000 400.0000  400.0000
 19    0      0   13 14:14:1:0        yes 3800.0000 400.0000  998.1960
 20    0      0   14 64:64:8          yes 2500.0000 400.0000  400.0000
 21    0      0   15 66:66:8          yes 2500.0000 400.0000  400.0000

perf stat results
     12.24 msec task-clock                       #    0.693 CPUs utilized             
       107      context-switches                 #    8.742 K/sec                     
        23      cpu-migrations                   #    1.879 K/sec                     
       329      page-faults                      #   26.879 K/sec                     
18,360,525      cpu_atom/cycles/                 #    1.500 GHz                         (24.46%)
21,167,060      cpu_core/cycles/                 #    1.729 GHz                         (75.54%)
19,495,339      cpu_atom/instructions/           #    1.06  insn per cycle              (24.46%)
34,945,740      cpu_core/instructions/           #    1.90  insn per cycle              (75.54%)
 3,627,048      cpu_atom/branches/               #  296.327 M/sec                       (24.46%)
 6,609,493      cpu_core/branches/               #  539.991 M/sec                       (75.54%)
    76,918      cpu_atom/branch-misses/          #    2.12% of all branches             (24.46%)
    65,568      cpu_core/branch-misses/          #    1.81% of all branches             (75.54%

